# How to I get id with $this->Auth->user() in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am implementing Auth in cakephp and I want to get user id in controller with:

```
$user = $this->Auth->user();
```

I have put

```
var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl');
```

on the top of the controller inside class.

When I search on google I found

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

and I also apply this code in my controller but I didn't get id.

When I print $user it print only username not id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> pr($this->Auth->user());

to print all the keys of Auth component, It can help to check if id actually exists in auth or not

Comment: When I print above code, it show Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [Username] => madhavi2
        )

)
It means id is not exists. How to I set id in Auth?

Comment: You need to use Auth for authentication purpose use Auth in AppController as

>public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'users'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);

See this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use anyone of below:

```
    1> $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
    2> $this->Auth->User('user_id');
    3> $uid = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
    4> $uid = $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']; 
    5> AuthComponent::user('id');
```

Comment: 4. is a nogo when you got the wrapper access for free.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Auth->user()
```

If the ID is not shown, maybe the 'User' model does not have an 'id' field or the id is not included in the Session? When I do this on my app, I see all the fields from the User model.
Or Did you extend the Auth Component to be custom ?